# How to call a controller function from angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call controller function from directive. Here is the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/Z5MBf/7/) I have a sayHello() function in controller. And I want to call that function from angular directive. If i wall like scope.sayHello();

```
scope.sayHello is not a function
```

I am getting like the above in console.

Answer (score 1):

To get your alert in your fiddle to fire, all I had to do what add the `person` into your template. You had the `updateparent="updatePerson()"`, and you just needed to pass the `person` in that call, like this: `updateparent="updatePerson(person)"`. Then your alert fired.

The reason for this is that you need to state in the template all of the parameters that you are passing in to the function. Since you call it like `updateparent({person: mandatePerson})`, you have to put the key `person` into your template that it will be called with that param. They have to match.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular directive's [link function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-) has arguments for both `scope` and `controller` -- if the method you want to call is directly on `$scope` in your controller you can just call it off of the scope arg-- if you are using `controllerAs` syntax (which I would recommend as it is a [recommended Angular pattern](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y030)) you can call it off the controller argument.

So, for your specific case (methods directly on `$scope`) in your directive `return` object you add a property `link`:

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn)
    scope.sayHello();
}
```

`link` runs once at directive creation-- if you want the `scope` or method to be available outside of that for some reason, assign it to a variable defined at the top level of the module.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your directive a bit, but this is how you get that sort of functionality.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/asarenski/Z5MBf/366/)

If you're interested in AngularJS I would highly recommend the John papa styleguide.
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

It will get you using syntax like controllerAs and will help make your code cleaner.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      Original name: {{mandat.name}}
    </div>
    <my-directive mandat="mandat"></my-directive>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.mandat = {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Doe",
    person: { id: 1408, firstname: "sam" }
  };
}

app.directive('myDirective', MyDirective);

function MyDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<div><input type='text' ng-model='mandat.person.firstname' /><button ng-click='updateparent()'>click</button></div>",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      mandat: "="
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.updateparent = function() {
        $scope.mandat.name = "monkey";
      }
    }
  }
}
```